# Calculating the optimal move in checkers

Tags: java

I created a checkress game and I would like the computer to calculate the most optimal move.
Here is what I've done so far:

```
public BoardS calcNextMove(BoardS bs)
{
    ArrayList<BoardS>options = calcPossibleOptions(bs);
    int max = -1;
    int temp;
    int bestMove = 0;

    for(int k=0;k<options.size();k++)
    {
        temp = calculateNextMove2(options.get(k));
        if(max<temp)
        {
            max = temp;
            bestMove = k;
        }
    }
    return options.get(bestMove);
}

public int calculateNextMove2(BoardS bs)
{
    int res = soWhoWon(bs);

    if(res == 2) //pc won(which is good so we return 1)
        return 1;
    if(res == 1)
        return 0;

    ArrayList<BoardS>options = calcPossibleOptions(bs);

    int sum = 0;
    for(int k=0;k<options.size();k++)
    {
        sum += calculateNextMove2(options.get(k));
    }
    return sum;
}
```

I keep getting

> > Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.StackOverflowError

calcPossibleOptions works good, it's a function that returns an array of all the possible options.

BoardS is a clas that represent a game board.

I guess I have to make it more efficient, how?

Comment: Is checkress the same thing as checkers?

Comment: sorry my bad I'll update.

Comment: Maybe the recursion in "calculateNextMove2" is going too deep? any idea how many times it's typically called before the end condition occurs (quite a lot I'd say...)?

Comment: That's for sure it's a checkers game.. well what can I do?I can't stop in the middle of the game. I have to play untill the end see if this way leads me to win or lose. Do you have a suggestion? I tried to run the recursion loop with one iteration "k<1" and I still get it the exception which means I'm so far away from efficiency

Comment: Well actually you need to stop at some point... like with chess e.g. (which I have more experience with) an engine will go maybe 20 moves deep commonly. If you ran it from the start of a chess game... it would literally run for 100s of years on current technology (and still not reach really be able to say what the winning first move is). Maybe just try 10 or 20 moves deep? (which would still beat most humans - and would still probably classify as "best move"). As with chess you  will have the difficulty of assessing a position as good or bad for this to work. *that* is the tricky part.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The recursion on "calculateNextMove2()" will run too deep and this is why you get a StackOverFlow. If you expect the game to run to the end (unless relatively close to an actual win) this may take a very long time indeed.  Like with chess e.g. (which I have more experience with) an engine will go maybe 20 moves deep before you will likely go with what it's found thus far. If you ran it from the start of a chess game... it can run for 100s of years on current technology (and still not really be able to say what the winning first move is). Maybe just try 10 or 20 moves deep? (which would still beat most humans - and would still probably classify as "best move"). As with chess you will have the difficulty of assessing a position as good or bad for this to work (often calculated as a combination of material advantage and positional advantage). That is the tricky part. Note: Project Chinook has done what you're looking to achieve - it has "defeated" the game of Checkers (no such thing exists yet for chess EDIT: Magnus Carslen has "deafeted" the game for all intents and purposes :D).

see: [Alpha-beta pruning](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alpha%E2%80%93beta_pruning)
(it may help somewhat)

Also here is an (oldish) paper I saw on the subject:

[Graham Owen 1997 Search Algorithms and Game Playing](http://www.gtryfon.demon.co.uk/bcc/Computer_chess/Graham/formcmp.htm)
(it may be useful)

Also note that returning the first move that results in a "win" is 'naive' - because it may be a totally improbably line of moves where the opponent will gain an advantage if they don't play in a very particular win - e.g. Playing for Fools Mate or Scholars Mate in chess... (quick but very punishable)

Comment: Let's say that I'm stopping after 20 moves, now how can I know who is in a better position?what should I return? And I know the mix max / alpha beta but as you can see I don't even use a a game tree.. I prefer the x moves going deep but again it leads me to what I wrote above

Comment: That's exactly the issue you now face... seriously. It is _the_ biggest challenge now. Maybe just to start, you can see who is the most material "up" to judge a position - i.e. with beginning move x (regardless of the moves after) player tends to be 2 pieces up after a y moves... and no other beginning move yields such an "advantage".

Comment: Also even 20 is high maybe... figure out how many move possibilities that actually is. (it is probably somewhere like (4*2)^20 - or 2^22 - pretty big number)

Answer (score 0):

You're going to need to find an alternative to MinMax, even with alpha-beta pruning most likely, as the board is too large making too many possible moves, and counter moves. This leads to the stack overflow.

I was fairly surprised to see that making the full decision tree for Tic-Tac-Toe didn't overflow myself, but I'm afraid I don't know enough about AI planning, or another algorithm for doing these problems, to help you beyond that.